# TeamCity agent seems to try to register itself every 3 minutes, resetting the agent, thus cancelling any builds

Tags: teamcity

I'm getting an issue where it seems that the TeamCity agent tries to register every 3 minutes (almost exactly on time as well), which makes the agent disconnected for a short amount of time. In this time, the build that was running on the agent gets cancelled since that agent is no longer valid. I've provided what the log looks like in the teamcity-agent.log file. Would anyone be able to figure out what's going on with this?

```
[2014-07-18 12:46:57,905]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=1, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9094, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='xjNGUZ3wZSuIXsp9Nheewm2OCswPb4SM'} 
[2014-07-18 12:46:57,922]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Server confirmed we are still registered 
[2014-07-18 12:46:57,942]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=1, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9093, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='Dt047mHCcR802PrkAOsoyzWx7LuCgeSM'} 
[2014-07-18 12:46:57,946]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9097, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='Jjii9Mgfti6ydxyJ64u0XSogkqUQJwZZ'} 
[2014-07-18 12:46:57,954]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Server confirmed we are still registered 
[2014-07-18 12:46:57,966]  ERROR - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Agent id=null. Another agent with name "phiperfapp07"(id=1) is registered on the server. Please check you do not have two agents with the same name. 
[2014-07-18 12:46:57,967]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging). 
[2014-07-18 12:46:58,015]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=1, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9095, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='sjHzskqbe8NISK5m3FM7QhmG7uN3rM76'} 
[2014-07-18 12:46:58,027]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Server confirmed we are still registered 
[2014-07-18 12:46:58,351]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9096, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='PxIJ3BVMtRPGkE5IPlRWVilyI59JnZkc'} 
[2014-07-18 12:46:58,370]  ERROR - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Agent id=null. Another agent with name "phiperfapp07"(id=1) is registered on the server. Please check you do not have two agents with the same name. 
[2014-07-18 12:46:58,370]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging). 
[2014-07-18 12:47:00,275]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9098, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='UeN00exlPdy16rs99g7Wkx8ZaO7iwxP1'} 
[2014-07-18 12:47:00,290]  ERROR - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Agent id=null. Another agent with name "phiperfapp07"(id=1) is registered on the server. Please check you do not have two agents with the same name. 
[2014-07-18 12:47:00,290]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging). 
[2014-07-18 12:47:00,967]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server has been restored 
[2014-07-18 12:47:01,370]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server has been restored 
[2014-07-18 12:47:03,291]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server has been restored 
[2014-07-18 12:47:58,282]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Updating agent parameters on the server: AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=1, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9095, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='sjHzskqbe8NISK5m3FM7QhmG7uN3rM76'} 
[2014-07-18 12:49:57,975]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=1, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9094, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='xjNGUZ3wZSuIXsp9Nheewm2OCswPb4SM'} 
[2014-07-18 12:49:57,991]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Server confirmed we are still registered 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,009]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=1, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9093, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='Dt047mHCcR802PrkAOsoyzWx7LuCgeSM'} 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,018]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Server confirmed we are still registered 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,022]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9097, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='Jjii9Mgfti6ydxyJ64u0XSogkqUQJwZZ'} 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,046]  ERROR - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Agent id=null. Another agent with name "phiperfapp07"(id=1) is registered on the server. Please check you do not have two agents with the same name. 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,047]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging). 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,081]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=1, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9095, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='sjHzskqbe8NISK5m3FM7QhmG7uN3rM76'} 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,092]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Server confirmed we are still registered 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,424]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9096, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='PxIJ3BVMtRPGkE5IPlRWVilyI59JnZkc'} 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,437]  ERROR - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Agent id=null. Another agent with name "phiperfapp07"(id=1) is registered on the server. Please check you do not have two agents with the same name. 
[2014-07-18 12:49:58,437]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging). 
[2014-07-18 12:50:00,347]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8080, AgentDetails{Name='phiperfapp07', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[9.70.214.180, 2002:946:d6b4:0:0:0:946:d6b4], Port=9098, Version='30101', PluginsVersion='30101-md5-fa151212818c29449df53fb0a8570f82', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken='006cd8e0b8607bb536e337977139ee55', PingCode='UeN00exlPdy16rs99g7Wkx8ZaO7iwxP1'} 
[2014-07-18 12:50:00,362]  ERROR - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Agent id=null. Another agent with name "phiperfapp07"(id=1) is registered on the server. Please check you do not have two agents with the same name. 
[2014-07-18 12:50:00,363]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging). 
[2014-07-18 12:50:01,047]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server has been restored 
[2014-07-18 12:50:01,438]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server has been restored 
[2014-07-18 12:50:03,363]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server has been restored
```

Comment: Have you `Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do next:
stop ur agent using

service.stop in agent/bin directory

and than in same directory use command

agent.bat start

Answer (score 0):

Teamcity is flagging this as duplicate agents. You probably have 2 agents that have

- Same agent name
- Same hostname portname combo
- Same autorization token